# Manual Consolidation with SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, crystal-reports, oracle-sqldeveloper, hana

I am trying to make a query to manually consolidate values. The  concept is "every -ve value should kick off +ve entries on the basis of FIFO"

Kindly help me in this regard. I have been doing this though stored procedure with a bunch of CASE expressions but still no success.

[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Please show us your existing code.

Comment: '"every -ve value should kick off +ve entries on the basis of FIFO"' - I have no idea what this means in relation to the sample data and what you want as a result.

Comment: @P.Salmon I have edited the question. Hope it will clear my question.

Comment: @MuhammadNomanSajid . . . One could speculate that "ve" somehow relates to `bal`, but the question is not clear.  The result set is also unclear.  Do you want four tables?  I might suggest that you delete this question and ask a new one -- one with data as *text tables* instead of images (or a db fiddle).  And try to be clearer on what you ware doing.  Fewer rows with simple references (1, 2, 3) would also make the data less distracting.

Answer (score 0):

It's like running an excel vlookup for =bal*-1 but in SQL format :) ......

```
SELECT      *
FROM        <table>
WHERE       (BAL <> BAL*-1)
```

should give you every row where the balance is not equal to *-1 of the other balance